# Custom Validation is only run once

Tags: c#, silverlight, validation, c#-4.0, data-annotations

I am creating an MVVM Silverlight application and am trying to add validation to my Model.

In this particular instance I have multiple phone number boxes and have the requirement that at least one phone number must be entered.  To facilitate I have my properties (HomePhone, WorkPhone, MobilePhone and OtherPhone) on my model decorated with an a CustomValidation attribute.

Example property:

```
    private string _otherPhone;
    [CustomValidation(typeof(MyModel), "ValidatePhoneNumbers")]
    public string OtherPhone
    {
        get { return _otherPhone; }
        set
        {
            if (_otherPhone == value) return;
            _otherPhone = value;
            Validator.ValidateProperty(value, new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "OtherPhone" });
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => HomePhone);
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => WorkPhone);
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => MobilePhone);
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => OtherPhone);
        }
    }
```

Along with the custom validator itself:

```
    public static ValidationResult ValidatePhoneNumbers(string number, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        MyModel myModel = (MyModel)validationContext.ObjectInstance;
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(myModel.HomePhone) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(myModel.WorkPhone) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(myModel.MobilePhone) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(myModel.OtherPhone)
                   ? new ValidationResult("At least one phone number must be entered")
                   : ValidationResult.Success;
    }
```

I have ensured that the backing store is set in the property setter before the validation is run, to ensure that the ValidatePhoneNumbers method is able to check the latest value.

When I try to save my model, I am executing UpdateBindingExpression on all the bindings in the View.  Now this works correctly the *first* time that I try to save, and all four fields are highlighted as having an error.

If I try to save again however, all fields are marked as passed validation, and a breakpoint in ValidatePhoneNumbers is never hit.  Why is this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure that every time that I spend long enough fighting a bug to resort to posting on SO, I work out what the actual answer is 20 seconds later... The `if (_otherPhone == value) return;` was causing the validation not to run - this optimisation would make sense if the validation wasn't dependent on another property.

Never mind...

Comment: Flip your if.... if (!value.equals(_otherPhone) { _otherPhone = value; //etc }, then after that do the stuff you wanna do whether the value being set was already the same or not.

Comment: But what would that achieve? The entire point of the if is to ensure the PropertyChanged isn't fired if it's not changed.

Comment: If you reread the comment it says *then after that do the stuff you wanna do whether the value being set was already the same or not*. So, if you did not want to do the RaisePropertyChanged items, they would go inside the if statement, not after it. Basically: `if (!value.Equals(_otherPhone) { //Do Stuff Here if Value Is Being Set } //Do Stuff outside the if that you want to do no matter what.`

Comment: In this case, I want to run every single line that is there, so the if statement would contain *just* the _otherPhone = value; hence the change would achieve nothing :) I understand where you're coming from though